# Buddy nicename and profile URL problems

Tags: url, profile, buddypress

I was wondering if anyone could help with my problem in Buddypress.

When a user with a special character in their username edits their profile '-2' is appended to their 'user_nicename' meaning that after a few edits their profile url can look like this

*http://www.domain.com/members/nicename-2-2-2-2-2/*

I have reset the 'user_nicename' field for affected users in the database and deleted the extra '-2s' but it just starts again. I have also tried adding

`define( ‘BP_ENABLE_USERNAME_COMPATIBILITY_MODE’, true );`

and also changing this to

`define( ‘BP_ENABLE_USERNAME_COMPATIBILITY_MODE’, false );`

in bp-custom.php and this makes no difference. I have just installed Buddypress and some users pre-existed with special characters in their username. I did find people with a similar problem on buddypress support (ticket/2642) however it is old and outdated and does not help me.

For some reason Buddypress support isn't working and won't let me post or I would ask there too. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Wordpress Version 3.5 / BuddyPress Version 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The profile field name is not the same as the slug/login name. Were the previous users added via a connect plugin?

You might want to add this plugin to allow users to change out their login name. http://buddydev.com/plugins/bp-username-changer

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have tried this and whilst the user can change their username (or nicename as I referred to it) as soon as they edit their profile again a '-2' appears again breaking links to their profile throughout the site which is the same as what was occuring when I manually edited the database field (user_nicename).